# Why my adding of two numbers does not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I managed to resolve this issue with a different method but i still don't understand why this method didn't work in the first place, i am probably missing something:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
*{padding: 10px}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function adding(){
var addnum1=parseInt(num1);
var addnum2=parseInt(num2);
var result=addnum1 + addnum2;
sum.value=result;
}

</script>

<input type="text" name="num1"><br>
<input type="button" value="+" disabled="true"><br>
<input type="text" name="num2"><br>
<input type="button" value="=" onclick="adding()"><br>
<input type="text" name="sum">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you explain the issue, it's a lot easier, as we don't have to randomly guess what's wrong with it ?

Comment: You aren't passing any arguments to the method or declaring num1 or num2 inside the method as being equal to anything.

Comment: Your function doesn't know what num1, num2, or sum are.

Comment: You're relying on a deprecated feature, `name` attribute isn't necessarily reflecting to global variables. Use `id` and `getElementById` method to get a reference to HTML elements.

Comment: Check this example and learn the basic concept: http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2009/07/27/add-two-numbers-3/

Comment: @Teemu I see, so basically i can't access the value of textbox named "num1" because "name" is not a global variable therefore isn't related to any specific value.

Comment: @IgorVojnović Exactly. Though the inputs have a value (an empty string if not entered any), `name` attributes don't create global JS variables (at least in modern browsers). That's why you need a DOM query method to get an element in JS.

Comment: @IsabelHM Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for the explanation. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example of a `jsfiddle` that you can use to learn better.

https://jsfiddle.net/pxpmp45v/2/

**JavaScript:**

```
function adding(){
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  var addnum1=parseInt(num1);
  var addnum2=parseInt(num2);
  var result= addnum1 + addnum2;
  var sum = document.getElementById('sum');
  sum.value=result;
}
```

**Your HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="num1"><br>
<input type="button" value="+" disabled="true"><br>
<input type="text" id="num2"><br>
<input type="button" value="=" onclick="adding()"><br>
<input type="text" id="sum">
```

Few things to note while retrieving value and assigning to a textbox:

> You must use `getElementById` method and assign a `id` attribute to your element. 
>    `<input type="text" id="num1">`
>   You must also retrieve the value of that element in your JavaScript otherwise you will get a `NaN`. Use this `document.getElementById('num2').value` instead of `document.getElementById('num2')`

Debugging help: Try `console.log` which prints your variables to your browsers console thus helping you identify what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link. Much gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

`num1`, `num2`, and `sum` aren't declared in your javascript.
You could give them IDs like

```
<input type="text" id="num1">
<input type="text" id="num2">
<input type="text" id="sum">
```

And then access them with `document.getElementById()`

```
function adding(){
    var addnum1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value);
    var addnum2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value);
    var result = addnum1 + addnum2;
    document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

While I have seen people accessing the values of inputs directly as global variables it not recommended. I would suggest using `getElementsByName` to access the values.

```js
function adding(){
  document.getElementsByName("sum")[0].value =
  parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("num1")[0].value) +
  parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("num2")[0].value); 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="num1"><br>
<input type="button" value="+" disabled="true"><br>
<input type="text" name="num2"><br>
<input type="button" value="=" onclick="adding()"><br>
<input type="text" name="sum">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your opinion is it better to use getElementsByName or getElementById? Or does it mostly depend on what we are try to do with the values we are accessing?

Comment: I only use `name` on inputs that will be submitted in a form, otherwise if there will be more than one of them I use `class` and if there will only ever be one of them and it is not submitted in a form then I use `id`